# Saving Leaflet.js maps as a static image

Tags: image, leaflet

I'm trying to find a good method for allowing end users to save Leaflet.js maps as a static image (e.g. PNG, JPG, etc.). Mapbox.js (built on top of Leaflet.js) provides a nice [method](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/#images), but I assume this requires having your maps hosted on Mapbox so that they have a Map ID through their API. Does anyone know how I can do this with a Leaflet.js map that cannot be called through an API? Such as my example [here](http://kingcountydata.weebly.com/socrata-test.html)?

Thank you all!
Eli

Answer (score 12):

This thread is a bit dated, at the time of this answer, but there are a few leaflet plugins that appear to tackle this now.

[Leaflet Print Plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport)